# How does graph of $f(x)$ correspond to a graph of its derivative $f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus

The derivative is a mesure of momentary change at a certain point. With this I'm fine. However, the derivative can be thought of and actually is an ordinary function, which can be plotted as a regular graph. Say, $f(x) = x^3$ and then $f'(x) = 3x^2$. If I render both of them on a same graph, I am a bit confused. How do I read and make sense of the graph of the derivative?

Let's take an $x_0 = 3$, $x_1 = 3,01$. Such a difference result to a following $y$-change $$3,01^3 - 3^3 = 0,270901$$ Then I'm trying to see what would derivative's function output: $3 \times 3^2 = 27$.

1. Can I state that momentary change around point $3$ is **approximately** $27$, however **precisely** is $0,279901$?
2. Can I state that due to positive change function output grows as long as argument grows?
3. What are some other fundmentally important statements I can conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $f'(x)$ measures the change in $f$ per change in $x$, so you should instead calculate $$\frac{3.01^3-3^3}{0.01}=27.0901$$ Which is the slope of the line passing through both $(3,f(3))$ and $(3.01,f(3.01))$. As these points get closer, the line approaches a tangent line with slope $f'(3)=3\cdot 3^2=27$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative isn't just the change. If that were the case, you would get even smaller numbers if you chose to compare $3^3$ to $3.0001^3$, or $3^3$ to $3.0000000000001^3$.

What the derivative does is to look at how much the value changes *compared to* how much the input changes. For instance, in your case we have a total change of
$$
3.01^3 - 3^3 = 0.270901
$$
This change happens with a change in $x$ of $3.01-3 = 0.01$. The derivative is (almost) the *ratio* between these two numbers:
$$
f'(3)\approx \frac{3.01^3-3^3}{3.01-3} = \frac{0.270901}{0.01} = 27.0901
$$
Picking a number closer to $3$ will give a better approximation:
$$
f'(3)\approx \frac{3.001^3-3^3}{3.001 - 3} = \frac{0.027009001}{0.001} = 27.009001
$$
and on it goes. Although I haven't rigorously proven it here, we see quite clearly that this way we seem to get close to the actual value you have for $f'(3)$, namely $3\cdot 3^2 = 27$.